# icuke with xcode 4 times out

Tags: iphone, xcode, cucumber, xcode4

Anyone get iCuke to work with XCode 4?

I'm trying to follow the iCuke tutorial at http://pragprog.com/magazines/2010-07/bdd-on-iphone-icuke

I get a time out error when trying to run the first feature:

```
Given "QuickContacts.xcodeproj" is loaded in the simulator # iCuke-0.6.3/lib/icuke/cucumber.rb:197
      execution expired (Timeout::Error)
      /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:64:in `start'
      /opt/local/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1035:in `request'
      features/add_contact.feature:7:in `Given "QuickContacts.xcodeproj" is loaded in the simulator'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had all kinds of problems getting this (more precisely iCuke in general) to work a few days ago.  I'm afraid in the end I abandonded it and went for [Frank](https://github.com/moredip/Frank) instead.

That said I had the same problem with Frank but I found a better solution to the problem than fixing the XCode integration (imho).  Take a look at [this project](https://github.com/Fingertips/ios-sim): I whipped up a cucumber step to boot my binaries in the simulator without the need for crufty Applescripts that convince XCode to do your bidding.  Perhaps you can do something similar for iCuke?

For anyone interested...our step looks something like this:

```
def run_app_in_simulator
  target = ENV['TARGET_PATH'] // how you set this is down to you....
  if not system('ios-sim', 'launch', target, '--verbose', '--sdk', '4.2', '--exit', '--family', 'ipad')
    raise "Unable to launch simulator"
  end
end
```

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have that cucumber step would you?

Comment: Updated with an example...HTH!

Comment: Are you sure about that --exit argument. The ios-sim doesn't seem to recognize it.

Comment: Yeah I am: check for a more recent fork of the project on github - it was added by someone other than the origina author: https://github.com/Fingertips/ios-sim

Comment: @ChristianSchlensker You need to take a look at the new offical iCuke fork - https://github.com/BlueFrogGaming/icuke

Answer (score 1):

After tinkering around a little bit in xcode, I was able to get past the timeout issue. 
It looks like this can be resolved if "Universal Access" is enabled:
Click on "Xcode -> Preferences->Documentation" , ensure that Universal Access is selected.